# Datagridview integer-column: can´t delete existing values

Tags: vb.net, validation, datagridview, dbnull

update: after trying a new DGV with the same table, some values etc etc, everything is fine... dont know why...

i have a Datagridview (DGV) bound to a table (the table in the DB has several columns [integer datatypes])

when entering an integer: everythings fine
when not entering an integer: the dataerror occurs and i handle it

but when i want to delete an existing integer or leave the value blank, the dataerror occours, too. saying "" is not an integer (ok, i know) but how can i handle this situation, to tell him to treat an "" as an dbnull.value or delete the existing value?

thank you

CellValidating-Event:

```
Private Sub dgvBunker_4N_CellValidating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs) Handles dgvBunker_4N.CellValidating

    If sender.Rows(e.RowIndex).IsNewRow Then Return
    If e.FormattedValue Is DBNull.Value Then Return
    If e.FormattedValue = String.Empty Then Return

    Select Case e.ColumnIndex
        Case 2 To 4
            If Not IsNumeric(e.FormattedValue) Then
                e.Cancel = True
                sender.Rows(e.RowIndex).ErrorText = "Not a valid Number"
            End If
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: give me code for better solution...

Comment: added. dont know if i have to handle this in this event, just asking for a hint, idea

the "If e.FormattedValue = String.Empty Then Return" works fine, if the datatype of the columns is a string, but not for int/double

Answer (score 2):

You can try following code. if value is not integer then validate that if value is blank or empty then `e.cancel = false`

```
Private Sub dgvBunker_4N_CellValidating(ByVal sender As Object,
          ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs)
          Handles dgvBunker_4N.CellValidating

    If sender.Rows(e.RowIndex).IsNewRow Then Return
    If e.FormattedValue Is DBNull.Value Then Return
    If e.FormattedValue = String.Empty Then Return

    Select Case e.ColumnIndex
        Case 2 To 4
            If Not IsNumeric(e.FormattedValue) Then
                If e.FormattedValue = "" Or IsDBNull(e.FormattedValue) Then
                    e.Cancel = False
                Else
                    e.Cancel = True
                    sender.Rows(e.RowIndex).ErrorText = "Not a valid Number"
                End If
            End If
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: for e.cancel = false: he wants a number as value, he keeps telling "a string.empty is not a number, cant parse etc etc" keeping the focus, forcing me to enter a number.
for e.cancel = true: i am trapped in this cell until i enter a number. but i dont get the errormessage.

but i want him to interpret a string.empty as an dbnull.value, so i can delete the number entered before.